# Выбрать нужное значение после запятой в строке

Tags: python, текст

Есть txt файл в котором содержатся подобные строки (их 60+):

```
grep_req_das: 10, 1, 1, 2
grep_req_says: 12, 3, 1, 30
ПРЕК.req: 20, 3, 1, 20
ПРЕК RI.req: 12, 3, 2, 80
...
```

И т.д. помогите обработать так, чтобы можно было взять второе, третье или четвертое значение (на выбор) и записать в файл. В итоге, чтобы получилось так, например, если выбрать второе:

```
grep_req_das: 1
grep_req_says: 3
ПРЕК.req: 3
ПРЕК RI.req: 3
```

Я использую split, но берётся только первое значение и записывается в файл:

```
with open('test.txt', 'r') as f:
    with open('test2.txt', 'w') as f1:
        all_str = f.read().splitlines()
        f1.write("%s\n" % all_str[0])
        for el in all_str[1:]:
            split_string = el.split(",", 1)
            substring = split_string[0]
            f1.write("%s\n" % substring)
```

Вывод:

```
    grep_req_das: 10
    grep_req_says: 12
    ПРЕК.req: 20
    ПРЕК RI.req: 12
```

Comment: Первая строка в файле всегда будет как в примере? Можно просто пропустить её обработку?

Comment: @nomnoms12 Можно пропустить, поправил в посте

Comment: вот вы в split вторым аргументом указали 1 - зачем? что написано в документации?

Comment: @strawdog maxsplit 1. Это число, которое говорит нам разделить строку на максимальное указанное количество раз. Если он не предусмотрен, значит, нет предела.

Comment: Разве это не задача csv?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вы можете воспользоваться регулярными выражениями:

```
import re

test_string = 'grep_req_says: 12, 3, 1, 30'

word = re.findall(r'[\D]+', test_string)[0]

number = re.findall(r'[\d]+', test_string)[здесь указываете номер значения, например 2]

print('{}{}'.format(word, number))
```

*Вывод: grep_req_says: 1*

Полный код:

```
import re

with open('test.txt', 'r') as f:
    with open('test2.txt', 'w') as f1:
        for line in f:
            word = re.findall(r'[\D]+', line)[0]
            number = re.findall(r'[\d]+', line)[2]
            f1.write('{}{}\n'.format(word, number))
```

Comment: Получаю: IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: на какой строчке? возможно последующие строки в вашем файле не подходят под условия регулярок, вот он и ругается

Comment: А нет все нормально)) Это я не убрал лишнее, спасибо все работает, как швейцарские часы

Comment: Зачем `[]` в регулярках?

Answer (score 2):

Разделите сначала по ":", потом по ",", без пределов.

```
test_string = 'grep_req_says: 12, 3, 1, 30'
key, valuesStr = test_string.split(":")
values = valuesStr.split(",")
print(key + ":" + values[0])
```